# TimSort minRun selection. Why is a perfectly balanced merge preferred over imbalanced merge?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, mergesort, timsort

In the "computing minrun" section of the [TimRun document](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listsort.txt), it gave a good and a bad example of selecting the minrun for N=2112 array. It states using minrun = 32 is inefficient because

> runs of lengths 2048 and 64 to merge at the end The adaptive gimmicks can do that with fewer than 2048+64 compares, but it's still more compares than necessary, and-- mergesort's bugaboo relative to samplesort --a lot more data movement (O(N) copies just to get 64 elements into place).

it also described the minrun = 32 algo as:

> then we've got a case similar to "2112", again
> leaving too little work for the last merge to do

It then stated that choosing minrun = 33 will end up with a perfectly balanced merge which is better.

> If we take minrun=33 in this case, then we're very likely to end up with 64
> runs each of length 33, and then all merges are perfectly balanced.  Better!

My questions are why is merging perfectly balanced sorted arrays better than imbalanced arrays if the total element count is the same(2112 in the example)?

why is minrun=32 "doing more compares than necessary" when the total element is also 2112 for minrun=33?

why is there "more data movement"?

why does the last merge have "too little work to do"?

My understanding is, merging sorted arrays of size A & size B will take O(A+B). Why is it more efficient when A & B are the same size?

I drew diagrams of how the 2 minrun scenarios are executed but I'm still confused.

[image: merge rules]

[image: bad min run example]

[image: good min run example]

[image: calcMinRun function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2112 elements if all runs are size 33, then it will take 6 steps to  merge from 33 to 2112: 33 -> 66 -> 132 -> 264 -> 528 -> 1056 -> 2112. If all runs are size 32, it will take 7 steps to merge from 32 to 2112: 32 -> 64 -> 128 -> 256 -> 512 -> 1024 -> 2048 -> 2112.

If you do the math, with minrun = 33, the entire array is processed in 6 steps, with minrun = 32, nearly the entire array (2048 elements) is processed in 6 steps, then the entire array is processed in the 7th step.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "merge pass"? It takes 63 merges when minrun=33

Comment: @LunaCall - I was making an analogy with bottom up merge sort. I updated my answer to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's a fresh perspective that I didn't think of. 
Your original answer mentioned the cost of copying which I think is the main issue of using minrun=32.

Time cost = comparing + copying. 


comparing takes the same amount of time because in total both have 2112 elements. 
copying cost more when there's more merge pass/step, as shown in your answer that minrun takes 1 more merge pass/step.
Therefore the time cost( of minrun = 32) > time cost( of minrun = 33).
Does this sounds right?

Comment: @LunaCall - that seems correct. I haven't implemented a timsort myself. Instead I've implemented a hybrid insertion sort and bottom up merge sort, where an initial pass using insertion sort is used to create sorted runs of 32 or 64 (on some systems, 16 may be better than 64), so that there are an even number of merge steps, then do a bottom up merge sort starting with the runs sorted by insertion sort. If there is existing order, the initial insertion sort pass will run faster.

Comment: @KellyBundy - I updated my answer to clarify it.

Comment: Now sounds right :-). Though something seems missing. I mean, using the same argument, let's do runs of 66 and tadaa, now we process the entire array only 5 times, so that's even better? And if you argue against that with "building runs of 66 is more costly than runs of 33" then I'll say "building runs of 33 is more costly than runs of 32".

Comment: @KellyBundy - assuming pseudo-random data, it depends on the system. The trade off is doing insertion sorts on runs of 66 elements versus 33 elements, versus 5 steps versus 6 steps. In my testing with somewhat similar approach, the difference ends up being small. For example, using a hybrid insertion + bottom up merge sort, on some older systems, with a fixed initial run size of 16 is a tiny bit faster than initial run size of 64, even though it's two more merge passes. Insertion sort on runs of 33 versus 32 elements is very little difference.